# Skrollr: fullPage.js compatibility

Tags: jquery, skrollr, slimscroll, fullpage.js

specifying this question: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/444

Source code can be found [here](http://codepen.io/obojdi/pen/40227a53bb06f3531c850dde5a757d28)

I want them kittehs 200x200 to move to center via skrollr data-attributes as I scroll inside second section. I.e. an instance of skrollr should affect 
`<div class="skrollr-1">`. Just don't get what is wrong. Console keeps quiet.

SlimScroll.js wraps div.skrollr-1 into two blocks:

```
<div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
<div class="scrollable" style="overflow: hidden;">
<div class="skrollr-1">
```

which is mentioned by the author to be inappropriate. But setting overflow:auto!important on these divs takes no effect.

**UPD** Since skrollr

> gets the scroll position from the window

I tried to use viewport mode as referenced in the docs, no effect.

**UPD2** Not quite sure if I got skrollr zen right, how the viewport mode is meant to work while sticking skrollr to DOM element is not provided?

**UPD3** FullPage.js developer reported that the problem is not with his plugin

Patience is the key as always. Universe-scale thanks for any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems skrollr only works over the window main scrolling.

You can read [a similar topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369648/using-skrollr-relative-to-an-element-not-the-window) and [here the discussion on its github issues forum](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/232).

#### Update

You can now use **skrollr** in combination with fullpage.js if you set the option `scrollBar:true` in fullpage.js. 
This will maintain the auto scrolling option but will show a scroll bar in the side. Which can be considered as a better practise form the user experience point of view.

[Here´s an online example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html) of fullpage.js with scrollBar:true.